# How to use vscode with SiteGround

Tags: web-hosting, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I am now developing Laravel-based website.
And this website is on SiteGround.
As you know, vscode makes our lives as developers so much easier.
So I want to work locally using vscode and relfect changes to siteground without uploading files manually.
I followed this guide below but it doesn't seem to help.
https://netosec.com/visual-studio-code-remote-sync-to-siteground-shared-hosting/

Please help me.

https://netosec.com/visual-studio-code-remote-sync-to-siteground-shared-hosting/
I tried to follow this guide several times, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you referenced is correct. A few months ago I tried to do the same thing to get it to work. The problem is that Siteground does not allow VS Code to properly install the "remote server" needed by VS Code. I read the article and it seems to leave out how to create SSH keys and use them which is what I am guessing is the problem.

From my experience understanding how SSH keys worked helped me troubleshoot the connection problem. You'll find some good info here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys

The VS Code extension used in the tutorial also has documentation listing out the connection parameters that must be defined. It can be found here:

<s>https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp</s>

### Update

The liximomo plugin is now deprecated. please use the following extension instead

Extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp

Configuration:
https://github.com/Natizyskunk/vscode-sftp/wiki/SFTP-only-Configuration